# C# InteropServices and Visual Basic 6.0 error reference error

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I created C# dll to use  with Visual Basic 6. When I create a reference in VB6 I get the error:

> Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

I tried to set the object of different ways but i still having the same problem.

VISUAL BASIC 6.0 Code:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()

 Dim objhacienda As SolcomFE.clsHacienda
 Set objhacienda = New SOLCOMFE.clsHacienda' Error can not create the object 429
 Dim blnResult As Boolean
 blnResult = objhacienda.tengoAcceso Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set
end sub
```

C# Code:

```c#
namespace SolcomFE
{


[
    ComVisible(true), //Hace visible las interfaces
    GuidAttribute("4F52E06E-29C6-4168-8AC2-F836CD7A1C4A"),  //Tomado del asembly del proyecto
    Description("Interfaces para acceso de factura electronica")
    //      ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)

    ]

//----------------------------------------------------Diseño de interfaces -------------------------------------//
public interface IclsHacienda
{

    [DispId(1)]
    bool tengoAcceso();

    [DispId(2)]
    void configuracion(bool pBlnEnvioProduccion,
                 string pStrUsuarioHacienda,
                 string pStrClaveHacienda,
                string pStrPinCerti,
                string pStrRutaCerti,
           string pStrRutaArchEnvio = "C://HACIENDA/Almacenamiento/",
                 string pStrRutaArchRespuesta = "C://HACIENDA/Almacenamiento/");

    [DispId(3)]
    string[] registrarDocElectronico(
                string pStrVerificador,
                 byte pBytSituacionEnCom,
                DocumentoEncabezado pLstEncabezadoDoc
                );
}


//-------------------------------------------Clases ---------------------------------------------------------//

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("64B7C116-BA68-4EE0-8340-74F64846CB3D")]
public class clsHacienda : IclsHacienda
{
    //------------------------------------------ Atributos de la clase --------------------------------------//


    private bool EnvioProduccion //
    {
        get
        {
            return envioProduccion;
        }
        set
        {
            envioProduccion = value;
        }
    }

    private string UsuarioHacienda //
    {
        get
        {
            return usuariohacienda;
        }
        set
        {
            usuariohacienda = value;
        }
    }

    private string ClaveHacienda //
    {
        get
        {
            return clavehacienda;
        }
        set
        {
            clavehacienda = value;
        }
    }
    private string RutaCertificado
    {
        get
        {
            return rutacertificado;
        }
        set
        {
            rutacertificado = value;
        }
    }



    private string RutaArchEnvio
    {
        get
        {
            return rutaarchenvio;
        }
        set
        {
            rutaarchenvio = value;
        }
    }

    private string RutArchrespuesta
    {
        get
        {
            return rutaarchrespuesta;
        }
        set
        {
            rutaarchrespuesta = value;
        }
    }


    private string PinCertificado
    {
        get
        {
            return pincertificado;
        }
        set
        {
            pincertificado = value;
        }
    }




    public clsHacienda() { } 

    public bool tengoAcceso() { return true; }


    public void configuracion(bool pBlnEnvioProduccion,
                 string pStrUsuarioHacienda,
                 string pStrClaveHacienda,
                string pStrPinCerti,
                string pStrRutaCerti,
           string pStrRutaArchEnvio = "C://HACIENDA/Almacenamiento/",
                 string pStrRutaArchRespuesta = "C://HACIENDA/Almacenamiento/")

    {
        EnvioProduccion = pBlnEnvioProduccion;

        UsuarioHacienda = pStrUsuarioHacienda;
        ClaveHacienda = pStrClaveHacienda;
        PinCertificado = pStrPinCerti;
        RutaCertificado = pStrRutaCerti;
        RutaArchEnvio = pStrRutaArchEnvio;
        RutArchrespuesta = pStrRutaArchRespuesta;
    }

    public string[] registrarDocElectronico(
                string pStrVerificador,
                 byte pBytSituacionEnCom,
                DocumentoEncabezado pLstEncabezadoDoc
                 )
    {
        string[] strArrValores = new string[10];
        return strArrValores;
    }




  }

}
```

Comment: 1. do not use the GUID from the assembly, create a new one
2. Register the assembly using regasm or use side-by-side by making a manifest
3. Use [assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

Comment: I already ads the asembly and compile and stil having the same problem.
Any other idea?

Comment: and i tried with Set o = CreateObject("SolcomFE.clsHacienda") and i get i can not create the object. I see the methods but i can not use it

Comment: Dim objhacienda As New SolcomFE.clsHacienda
 
  Set objhacienda = objhacienda
Dim blnResult As Boolean
The function below only returns true
blnResult = objhacienda.tengoAcceso() // Error wainting for function or variable

Comment: Are you compiling 32 bit. VB6 can only use 32 bit dlls although it can use 64 bit exes.

Comment: When i compling in c# y select any cpu option,  or there is another option that i have to check for compiling 32 bit?

Comment: and i get the error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Cannot register assembly "C:\HACIENDA\FE2\FESOLCOM\bin\Debug\FESOLCOM.dll" - access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator. Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FESOLCOM.clsHacienda' is denied. FESOLCOM   
son i use the next command for register the component REGASM solcomfe.dll /tlb:com.solcomfe.tlb

Comment: i compile with any cpu and i comple with x86 and i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find out whats wrong. Specially because i don't have VB6 ;-). Anyway, I've found some differences on your implementation. Check if this rings a bell:

Interfaces:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("E449B0E6-2F27-46B7-9CC0-C7032B7B5BF1")]
public interface IclsHacienda
{
    [DispId(1)]
    bool tengoAcceso();

    [DispId(2)]
    void configuracion(bool pBlnEnvioProduccion,
                 string pStrUsuarioHacienda,
                 string pStrClaveHacienda,
                string pStrPinCerti,
                string pStrRutaCerti,
                string pStrRutaArchEnvio,
                string pStrRutaArchRespuesta);

    [DispId(3)]
    string[] registrarDocElectronico(
                string pStrVerificador,
                 byte pBytSituacionEnCom,
                 IDocumentoEncabezado pLstEncabezadoDoc
                );
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("97F8901F-EEDA-4DE1-8B4B-826ED43E17D8")]
public interface IDocumentoEncabezado
{
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("4726F93F-D102-442E-AF7D-3255B87E740C")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IDocumentoEncabezado))]
public class DocumentoEncabezado : IDocumentoEncabezado
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("500941FB-3F7B-4285-BF4A-A642D60AD923")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IclsHacienda))]
public class ClsHacienda : IclsHacienda
{
    public void configuracion(bool pBlnEnvioProduccion, string pStrUsuarioHacienda, string pStrClaveHacienda, string pStrPinCerti, string pStrRutaCerti, string pStrRutaArchEnvio , string pStrRutaArchRespuesta)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Called configuracion");
    }

    public string[] registrarDocElectronico(string pStrVerificador, byte pBytSituacionEnCom, IDocumentoEncabezado pLstEncabezadoDoc)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Called registrarDocElectronico");
        return new string[] { "Whatever" };
    }

    public bool tengoAcceso()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Called tengoAcceso");
        return false;
    }
}
```

If not, there is something wrong on the VB side...

Comment: I apply the fixes but i still having the same error, i can add  and use com dll    built in vb6 without problem, but not in c#

Comment: I can't test it on VB but in Delphi it's working fine. There must be something special on how to import in VB. Did you check this post: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/817248/how-to-call-a-visual-basic--net-or-visual-basic-2005-assembly-from-vis

Comment: when i  check  Register for COM Interop  i always get the error

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Cannot register assembly "C:\HACIENDA\FE2\FESOLCOM\bin\Debug\FESOLCOM.dll" - access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator. Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FESOLCOM.clsHacienda' is denied. FESOLCOM.    so  i  run  from developer command REGASM solcomfe.dll /tlb:com.solcomfe.tlb

Comment: you need administrator rights to register. Run the command prompt as admin and run regasm again

Comment: when i run from command prompt y can register the component, but i when i called from vb6 i get the above error

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for your help.

I found a solution
create 2 clases, one inteface class, another method class
Example iInterface, COMInterface,
COMIterface implements iInterface.

Go to tools and create GUID
Then create a key. Implement_OleCreate and paste it to iInterface class,
After create a new key a 5.Guid Class

More documentation

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37338.com-interop-detail-steps-to-create-com-interop-dll.aspx